# Showing a that the derivative exists on every $x$ but is not continuous at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

So the question goes as following:

Let $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ if $x\not=0$

show that $f'(x)$ exist at every $x$ but $f'$ is not continous at $x=0$.

I'm not really sure how to show it.

Usually I would show that when x approaches 0 from either side it will have different limits, but this is clearly not the case here.

All help is welcomed!

Comment: in order for a function to be characterized discontinuous at some point $x_0$, this point must be in the domain of the function. If so, what is the value of your function $f(x)$ at $x_0=0$ ?

Comment: The discontinuity at $x=0$ is removable, so the function is extended to $f(0)=0$. The derivative at $0$ is $0$. It remains to check that $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)$ either does not exist, or does exist but is not $0$. (hint: it's the former)

Comment: Right. But do I have to define f(0)=0? if it does not exist?

Comment: First step: take the derivative away from zero, using the chain rule

Comment: Yes, you have to define $f(0)=0.$ If the problem didn't do this for you, it is not correctly posed.

Comment: Second step, take the derivative at zero, using the Newton quotient.

Comment: Third step: compare

Comment: I got $f'(x)=2xsin(\frac{1}{x})-cos(\frac{1}{x})$ usually I would factor the derivative inorder to make it differentiable at f'(0).

Comment: factor the derivative? make it differentiable? No one asked you to find the derivative of the derivative (aka second derivative). The question before you is whether this function $f'(x)$ is continuous. What value does $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ approach as $x$ approaches 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement goes something like this:

The function 
$$
f(x)=\left\{ 
     \begin{array}{c}
     x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}), \ \ x\neq 0 \\
     0, \ \ x=0
     \end{array}
     \right.
$$
is differentiable everywhere and (thus) continuous everywhere.

Its derivative (use product + chain rule of differentiation for $x\neq 0$ and apply the definition of the derivative at $x=0$) is:
$$
f'(x)=\left\{ 
     \begin{array}{c}
     2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x}), \ \ x\neq 0 \\
     0, \ \ x=0
     \end{array}
     \right.
$$
which is discontinuous at $x=0$. (the limit of the upper branch for $x\rightarrow 0$ does not exist).

**P.S.:** Here is a quick argument to show why $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\big(2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})\big)$$ does not exist: Let us suppose that the limit exists and is a real number $l$: 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\big(2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})\big)=l\in\mathbb{R}$$
Thus:
$$
\cos(\frac{1}{x})=2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})-f'(x), \ \ \ \ x\neq 0 
$$
and since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x \sin(\frac{1}{x}\big)=0$ (remember that:  $0\times bounded = 0$), after taking limits at $x\rightarrow 0$ of both sides of the last equation we arrive at: 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\cos(\frac{1}{x})=-l\in\mathbb{R}
$$
which is clearly absurd, since it is well known (and almost evident) that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist.

Comment: right. 

However in the formula in my book they explain it as following: $f'(x)=lim_{h->0}\frac{f(h)}{h} =lim_{h->0}hsin(\frac{1}{h})=0$  I'm not quite sure what they did. They redfined the derivative for the function?

Comment: They probably mean that: $f'(x)=lim_{h->0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0} =lim_{h->0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$. (remeber that by definition: $f(0)=0$).

Comment: I think that I get it now. Your latest edit was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

For $x\ne 0$,

$$f'(x)=2x\sin (1/x)-\cos (1/x) $$

$\lim_0 2x\sin (1/x)=0$

$\lim_0 \cos (1/x) $ doesn't exist.

so $\lim_0 f'(x)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

There are several helpful comments and answers already, but I want to point out this line:

> Usually I would use show that when $x$ approaches $0$ from either side **it** will have different limits, but this is clearly not the case here.

Beware of pronouns! What you mean by *it* here?  Based on what you write next, it sounds like you're looking at 
$$
    \lim_{x\to 0} x^2 \sin(1/x) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)
$$
You are right that his limit does exist (it equals zero).  But that just tells you the function is continuous at $0$.

You want to show $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $0$.  That means you are looking at the limit
$$
    \lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)
$$
Once you calculate what $f'(x)$ is away from zero, you will see why the limit above does not exist.